# Fabric can't see any but any errors&crashes&non fatals on dashboard

Tags: unity-game-engine, crashlytics, google-fabric

I have just installed Fabric to my unity project succesfully and I can get active-users information clearly. But I cannot even see any crash reports on dashboard. I just tried all exception styles like crash &  throw non fatal method but I couldn't get any report.

I made pod installs for fabric and crashlytics.
I have setup succesfully for fabric instructions for ios & unity.

I don't know how I cannot see still any report?

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. What output do you see when running the app after a crash?

Comment: just solved the problem, thanks!